Unable to include thrust/host_vector.h and others with CUDA 12.5
This test program compiled fine with CUDA 12.4 and lower, but fails to compile w/ 12.5.1:
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  thrust::host_vector<int> h_vec(5);
  h_vec[0] = 1;
  h_vec[1] = 2;
  h_vec[2] = 3;
  h_vec[3] = 4;
  h_vec[4] = 5;

  thrust::inclusive_scan(h_vec.begin(), h_vec.end(), h_vec.begin());

  for(int i = 0; i < h_vec.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << h_vec[i] << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

Build and output:
$ g++-13 -std=c++17 -I/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include inclusive_scan.cpp -lthrust
In file included from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_device.cuh:52,                                    
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/system/cuda/detail/util.h:48,                  
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/system/cuda/detail/internal/copy_cross_system.h:49,
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/system/cuda/detail/copy.h:111,                      
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/system/detail/adl/copy.h:50,                        
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/detail/copy.inl:31,                                 
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/detail/copy.h:98,                            
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/detail/allocator/copy_construct_range.inl:31,
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/detail/allocator/copy_construct_range.h:53,
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/detail/contiguous_storage.inl:31,
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/detail/contiguous_storage.h:243,
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/detail/vector_base.h:39,
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/host_vector.h:35,
                 from inclusive_scan.cpp:1:
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_ptx.cuh: In function ‘void cub::CUB_200400___CUDA_ARCH_LIST___NS::CTA_SYNC()’:
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_ptx.cuh:271:5: error: ‘__syncthreads’ was not declared in this scope
  271 |     __syncthreads();
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_ptx.cuh: In function ‘int cub::CUB_200400___CUDA_ARCH_LIST___NS::CTA_SYNC_AND(int)’:
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_ptx.cuh:280:12: error: ‘__syncthreads_and’ was not declared in this scope
  280 |     return __syncthreads_and(p);
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_ptx.cuh: In function ‘int cub::CUB_200400___CUDA_ARCH_LIST___NS::CTA_SYNC_OR(int)’:
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_ptx.cuh:289:12: error: ‘__syncthreads_or’ was not declared in this scope
  289 |     return __syncthreads_or(p);
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_ptx.cuh: In function ‘void cub::CUB_200400___CUDA_ARCH_LIST___NS::WARP_SYNC(unsigned int)’:
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_ptx.cuh:298:5: error: ‘__syncwarp’ was not declared in this scope
  298 |     __syncwarp(member_mask);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_ptx.cuh: In function ‘int cub::CUB_200400___CUDA_ARCH_LIST___NS::WARP_ANY(int, unsigned int)’:
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_ptx.cuh:307:12: error: ‘__any_sync’ was not declared in this scope
  307 |     return __any_sync(member_mask, predicate);
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_ptx.cuh: In function ‘int cub::CUB_200400___CUDA_ARCH_LIST___NS::WARP_ALL(int, unsigned int)’:
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_ptx.cuh:316:12: error: ‘__all_sync’ was not declared in this scope
  316 |     return __all_sync(member_mask, predicate);
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_ptx.cuh: In function ‘int cub::CUB_200400___CUDA_ARCH_LIST___NS::WARP_BALLOT(int, unsigned int)’:                                                                                               
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_ptx.cuh:325:12: error: ‘__ballot_sync’ was not declared in this scope
  325 |     return __ballot_sync(member_mask, predicate);                                                               
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                        /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_ptx.cuh: In function ‘unsigned int cub::CUB_200400___CUDA_ARCH_LIST___NS::SHFL_IDX_SYNC(unsigned int, int, unsigned int)’:                                                                      
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_ptx.cuh:368:12: error: ‘__shfl_sync’ was not declared in this scope     
  368 |     return __shfl_sync(member_mask, word, src_lane);                                                            
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                          
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_ptx.cuh: In function ‘int cub::CUB_200400___CUDA_ARCH_LIST___NS::RowMajorTid(int, int, int)’:                                                                                                   
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_ptx.cuh:415:39: error: ‘threadIdx’ was not declared in this scope
  415 |     return ((block_dim_z == 1) ? 0 : (threadIdx.z * block_dim_x * block_dim_y)) +                               
      |                                       ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda/std/detail/libcxx/include/__cuda/ptx/instructions/barrier_cluster.h:30,
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda/std/detail/libcxx/include/__cuda/ptx.h:74,
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda/ptx:19,
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda/discard_memory:25,
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_device.cuh:57:
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda/std/detail/libcxx/include/__cuda/ptx/ptx_helper_functions.h: In function ‘uint32_t cuda::ptx::__4::__as_ptr_smem(const void*)’:
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda/std/detail/libcxx/include/__cuda/ptx/ptx_helper_functions.h:40:44: error: ‘__cvta_generic_to_shared’ was not declared in this scope
   40 |   return static_cast<_CUDA_VSTD::uint32_t>(__cvta_generic_to_shared(__ptr));
      |                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda/std/detail/libcxx/include/__cuda/ptx/ptx_helper_functions.h: In function ‘uint64_t cuda::ptx::__4::__as_ptr_gmem(const void*)’:
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda/std/detail/libcxx/include/__cuda/ptx/ptx_helper_functions.h:60:44: error: ‘__cvta_generic_to_global’ was not declared in this scope
   60 |   return static_cast<_CUDA_VSTD::uint64_t>(__cvta_generic_to_global(__ptr));
      |                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda/std/detail/libcxx/include/__cuda/ptx/ptx_helper_functions.h: In function ‘_Tp* cuda::ptx::__4::__from_ptr_smem(size_t)’:
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda/std/detail/libcxx/include/__cuda/ptx/ptx_helper_functions.h:73:33: error: there are no arguments to ‘__cvta_shared_to_generic’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘__cvta_shared_to_generic’ must be available [-fpermissive]
   73 |   return reinterpret_cast<_Tp*>(__cvta_shared_to_generic(__ptr));
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda/std/detail/libcxx/include/__cuda/ptx/ptx_helper_functions.h:73:33: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda/std/detail/libcxx/include/__cuda/ptx/ptx_helper_functions.h: In function ‘_Tp* cuda::ptx::__4::__from_ptr_gmem(size_t)’:
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda/std/detail/libcxx/include/__cuda/ptx/ptx_helper_functions.h:94:33: error: there are no arguments to ‘__cvta_global_to_generic’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘__cvta_global_to_generic’ must be available [-fpermissive]
   94 |   return reinterpret_cast<_Tp*>(__cvta_global_to_generic(__ptr));
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_device.cuh: In static member function ‘static typename AgentT::TempStorage& cub::CUB_200400___CUDA_ARCH_LIST___NS::detail::vsmem_helper_impl<AgentT>::get_temp_storage(cub::CUB_200400___CUDA_ARCH_LIST___NS::NullType&, cub::CUB_200400___CUDA_ARCH_LIST___NS::detail::vsmem_t&)’:
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_device.cuh:160:63: error: ‘blockIdx’ was not declared in this scope
  160 |       static_cast<char*>(vsmem.gmem_ptr) + (vsmem_per_block * blockIdx.x));
      |                                                               ^~~~~~~~
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_device.cuh: In static member function ‘static bool cub::CUB_200400___CUDA_ARCH_LIST___NS::detail::vsmem_helper_impl<AgentT>::discard_temp_storage(typename AgentT::TempStorage&)’:
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_device.cuh:201:38: error: ‘threadIdx’ was not declared in this scope
  201 |     const std::size_t linear_tid   = threadIdx.x;
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_device.cuh:202:50: error: ‘blockDim’ was not declared in this scope
  202 |     const std::size_t block_stride = line_size * blockDim.x;
      |                                                  ^~~~~~~~

The above errors are specifically for gcc-13.3 and cuda-12.5.1.
However it compiles and runs fine with cuda-12.4, using either gcc 12 or 14.
OS: arch linux kernel 6.9.10.
We have a hybrid project with both .cpp and .cu files and have been using the above code in a .cpp file. I would have expected thrust::host_vector<> and related functions to be compilable w/ gcc as opposed to nvcc. Did this change in CUDA 12.5?
(Note that this test is a MRE for a larger project, so a simple answer like "just use nvcc" is not what I'm looking for.)

The error seems to point at host_vector.h rather than scan.h.

The problematic code seems to have been removed again from cub/util_device.cuh (it got its own header) in this PR. So you could try using the latest CCCL 2.5.0 from GitHub instead of CCCL 2.4.0 included with the CUDA Toolkit 12.5 and see if it fixes the issues. See here for how to do that.

The error seems to point at host_vector.h rather than scan.h. Indeed, sorry about that. #include <thrust/host_vector.h> eclipses similar errors that would otherwise show for #include <thrust/scan.h>. Thanks for the note about the potential fix. I'll wait for it to make its way into a package,

The code compiles fine for me with CUDA 12.4 (CCCL 2.3.1). I can reproduce the issue when using CCCL 2.4 and it is gone again with CCCL 2.5 as hypothesized (both using CUDA 12.4 as I don't have 12.5 installed yet).
